# Google maps border-radius not respected on mobile

Tags: css, google-maps

I have a straight-forward google maps element, with a border-radius. Looks solid on the desktop, but on mobile, the corners of the map are not rounded, but there is a rounded border behind the map.

I've searched everywhere online and cannot find a solution that works - is this a limitation of google maps, or am I missing something CSS-wise?

```
<div id="search_params">
     <h3 id="search_by_address_text">search by address</h3>
     <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="">
     <div id="map"></div> 
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>

  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: #798589 4px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    max-width: 99%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Desktop View:
[image: desktop view]

Mobile View:
[image: mobile view]

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the border to the container, rather than the map itself, hence why it goes over the border on mobile (the map's height increases)

Try adding the border to the iframe instead.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I don't have an iframe - I updated the question with my HTML. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Any styles to `iframe` were also not being adhered to, so I solved this by styling the child div of the map like so:

```
  #map > div {
      border-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(#798589, #798589);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
```